# postgresql filter data from bytea column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table where i am saving data in a column of type bytea, the data is actually a JSON object.
I need to implement a filter on the JSON data.

```
SELECT  cast(job_data::TEXT as jsonb) FROM job_details where job_data ->> "organization" = "ABC";
```

This query does not work.
The JSON Object looks like

```
{
    "uid": "FdUR4SB0h7",
    "Type": "Reference Data Service",
    "user": "hk@ss.com",
    "SubType": "Reference Data Task",
    "_version": 1,
    "Frequency": "Once",
    "Parameters": "sdfsdfsdfds",
    "organization": "ABC",
    "StartDateTime": "2020-01-20T10:30:00Z"
}
```

Comment: You should always use the appropriate data type (in this case `jsonb`) so that your queries are simple and perform well.

Comment: Why are you storing a JSON value in a `bytea` column?  That's not a good choice. You should use the `jsonb` or `json` data type for that.

Comment: it been done by quartz .net scheduler, I need to just query data as per need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to predicate on the converted column, also, that conversion may not necessarily work depending on encoding. Try something like this:

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM
    job_details
WHERE
    convert_from(job_data, 'UTF-8')::json ->> 'organization' = 'ABC';
```